# Can an extension detect Google Chrome's home page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to detect Google Chrome's home page via the chrome.* extension API, or any other way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is no API call for this. The closest I could get was to run `chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow` in the beginning of a background page and then analyze returned tabs.

```
chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null, function(tabs) {
    if(tabs.length == 1 && tabs[0].status == "loading") {
        console.log("possible home page:", tabs[0].url);
    }
});
```

This would work most of the times, but if your extension will be enabled when current window happens to have 1 tab which is currently loading - it would return wrong url. So you need to implement check to at least not run this code during first extension installation (by using some `localStorage` flag).